# Please explain the meaning of this C++ template code

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename HELPER_>
class A{
     public:

        typedef HELPER_ HELPER ;
        typedef typename HELPER::TRAITS_  TRAITS_2;
     // other stuff....
};
```

My question is that `HELPER_` is a type , then `HELPER` will also be a type, then what does `HELPER::TRAITS`_ signify. similarly if `HELPER` is not the name of class, it is just an unknown type being specified. But in the above code it feels like `HELPER` is the name of the class and it is calling its public variable name `TRAITS_`.

**I want to know what the above code means.**

Comment: The above code is not valid at all, it is very hard to work out what it means. Please post a more complete sample.

Comment: The name of this question isn't very helpful. You should at least mention typedefs and the `::`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef HELPER_ HELPER ;
```

Aliases `HELPER_` as `HELPER` in class namespace, so `A<B>::HELPER` becomes equivalent to `B`. It can useful in template code.

```
typedef typename HELPER::TRAITS_  TRAITS_2;
```

Aliases `HELPER::TRAITS`_ as `TRAITS_2` in class namespace, so `A<B>::TRAITS_2` becomes equivalent to `B::TRAITS_`. `typename` is necessary, becouse compiler doesn't know that `HELPER::TRAITS_` is a type without definition of HELPER.

Comment: sir,thanks for your explanation but i din't get the concept that how A<B>::HELPER becomes equivalent to B.

Comment: Imagine A<B> (pseudocode): `class A<B> { public: typedef B HELPER; ... };`.

Answer (score 1):

This code is assuming that for any `HELPER_` template parameter used, `HELPER_::TRAITS_` exists and is a typename.

**What the code is actually doing:**

For a type `X`, this code is establishing that `A<X>::TRAITS_2` is defined as the same type as `X::TRAITS_`

Answer (score 1):

The code is allowing you to specify customized traits in the template class by using a separate class to specify those traits. It uses typedef to help complete the abstraction. For example, you could set up a trait class so that `A::TRAITS_` works out to be `int` like this (noting that type names in all caps with a trailing underscore are somewhat uncommon):

```
class MyTraits
{
public:
    typedef int TRAITS_;
};

template<typename HELPER_>
class A{
     public:

        typedef HELPER_ HELPER ;
        typedef typename HELPER::TRAITS_  TRAITS_2;
     // other stuff....
};

// A<MyTraits>::TRAITS_2 is now `int`.
```

Answer (score 0):

`TRAITS_` is a **nested name** inside whatever `HELPER_` happens to be. Since `typename` is put in front of this nested name, it's expected to signify a **type**.

Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct X{
  typedef typename T::some_type some_type;
  X(some_type const& p)
    : m(p) {}

private:
  some_type m;
};

struct A{
  typedef int some_type;
};

struct B{
  typedef std::string some_type;
};

int main(){
  X<A> x1(5);
  X<B> x2("hi");
  std::cout << "X<A>::m = " << x1.m << ", X<B>::m = " << x2.m "\n";
}
```

Output:

> X<A>::m = 5, X<B>::m = hi